# Register a filetype association with xdg-mime under Linux

Tags: linux, mime, file-type, xdgutils

I'm trying to get xdg-open to run mplayer to open WMV files.

The manual says to register the filetype with xdg-mime to a mime type, then to register a .desktop file to open the mime type.

I don't succeed to register the filetype:

```
cam@x ~ $ file toto.wmv 
toto.wmv: Microsoft ASF
cam@x ~ $ xdg-mime query filetype toto.wmv 
application/octet-stream; charset=binary
cam@x ~ $ cat ms-wmv.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
<mime-type type="video/x-ms-wmv">
 <comment>video microsoft</comment>
 <glob pattern="*.wmv"/>
</mime-type>
</mime-info>
cam@x ~ $ xdg-mime install ms-wmv.xml 
cam@x ~ $ xdg-mime query filetype toto.wmv 
application/octet-stream; charset=binary
cam@x ~ $
```

I was expecting the last command would return video/x-ms-wmv.

What am I missing?

Comment: Shouldn't this be under Superuser or Tex/Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at:

```
/usr/share/mime/video
```

for the corresponding ms-wmv.xml file? is it changed after

```
xdg-mime install ms-wmv.xml
```

Perhaps the problem comes that executing the command the file is saved in *~/.local/share/mime* and then in the global mime-type description is written:

```
<sub-class-of type="video/x-ms-asf"/>
```

Perhaps changing the file */usr/share/mime/video/ms-wmv.xml* will do the trick, or otherwise, removing the file from the global mime dir, in order that the system starts using the one in your personal directory